# Based on the line item descriptions in 10Ks, how do I find the corresponding terminology under US_GAAP_2019 taxonomy analyzer?

Tags: accounting, reit, edgar

For example, if I'm looking at the 10K for AVB and under its reconciliation of FFO, I see a description of "Gain on sale of previously depreciated real estate", how do I find the corresponding tag/code/id (format: us-gaap_ProfitLossFromRealEstateOperations)?

I'm trying to find it because the SEC api accepts tags according to that format, but I cannot seem to find an online source directly translating some non-GAAP/non-IFRS items like FFO/NOI or even the constituents of FFO/NOI into tags that I can look up.

I would be happy to get a direct tag for FFO or Core FFO, but I'm under the belief that I need to build it myself, which is why I'm looking for that particular tag.

I need this for personal finances because I will use this data to create a dashboard tracking investments made for my personal finances.

What's the proper workflow to get around this?

Comment: Despite the availability of the "accounting" tag, accounting per se is usually out of bounds here unless you can explain why you need it for *personal* (finances and money).

Comment: @keshlam thank you. this seemed to be the most appropriate stackexchange given the options. I will look for answers elsewhere.

Comment: Edit: I chose to explain why I need it for personal finances.

Comment: You may be using it for *your* personal needs, but this is a very technical question deep into the accounting field, and I think is very much off-topic here.

Comment: it's not even an accounting question... it's a technical question regarding the SEC's API for developers.